# Auto resize a JPanel in multiples of 50

Tags: java, swing, layout

I need to design an interface where i have a InnerPanel that resizes with the OutterPanel. Ok, the problem is that i need the InnerPanel to resize only in multiples of 50.

So, if the OutterPanel has 50px, the InnerPanel has 50px. If the OutterPanel resizes to 80px, the InnerPanel stays sized at 50px. But when the OutterPanel gets resized to 110px, the InnerPanel goes to 100px.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: As suggested, I'm posting the question of what I've tryed so far...
In the constructor of the OutterPanel I've added a ComponentListener to resize the InnerPanel:

```
JPanel OutterPanel = this;

this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        contentArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(OutterPanel.getPreferredSize().width, 500));
    }
});
```

The Listener itself is working, the problem is that OutterPanel.getPreferredSize().width, is always returning 0.
For some reason, OutterPanel.getPreferredSize().height return the real height.

How can I retrieve the OutterPanel width? And whats the best path to set the InnerPanel size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the inner panel.

Maybe something like:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    Dimension parentSize = getParent().getSize();
    int width = (parentSize.width / 50) * 50;
    int height = (parentSize.height / 50) * 50;
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}
```

Comment: Worked very well without the need of anything else. I know that I'm asking much, but care to give a light whats happening? When Swing is using the Inner Panel getPreferredSize to define its own size?

Comment: @Psyny, glad it helped. It won't work in all situations. That is I don't expect it to work with layout that respect the preferred size of a component when you pack the frame. For example it won't work if you add the outer panel to the NORTH of a BorderLayout because as you expect the preferred size will be 0. It will work when you add the outer panel to the CENTER because the CENTER will get all the extra space and it doesn't recognize the preferred size of the component added to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSize()`, not `getPreferredSize()`. When the outer panel is resized, its size changes but its preferred size does not change.

Comment: Also, you should think about resetting the bounds of the inner panel in the outer panel's paintComponent() method, rather than artificially changing the inner panel's preferred size. Note that the preferred size is a hint, not an absolute; the layout manager might ignore the preferred size of the children.